# PHP in math operations I have strange issue

Tags: php, operation

why `echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);` result is **7** ?

I was surprised when get value 7 ? I dont understand why ?

[**HERE IS A LINK**](http://codepad.org/xZL6rVn9)

Comment: sorry... result is 7 !!!

Comment: 0.1 + 0.7 = 0.79999998956919 in IEE 754 doubles (due to FP rounding errors).  Truncating to `int` will give 7.

Comment: I dont get a answer from the linked question @John Conde are you sure the questions are same ?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Yeah I thought it'd be that @Alnitak

Comment: Yeah they are the same.